# Why my transactions-private GETH node- take minutes to propagate?

Tags: go-ethereum

Why my transactions-private GETH node- take minutes to propagate?  How can I optimize this? Can I broadcast the same transaction to multiple nodes to speed up the propagation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a private geth node then you will need to allow other nodes to connect to your network before being able to propagate the transactions to them. Also I would suggest checking your version of geth that you are using. type geth -v into a fresh terminal and you will see the version of geth that you are using. For reference on setting up a local development geth node you can you "geth --dev console" in a terminal window  for a local client on your machine.

To send a transaction you must follow these steps

var acct1 = eth.accounts[0]

personal.newAccount(testnet)

var acct2 = eth.accounts[1]

eth.sendTransaction({from: acct1, to: acct2, value: web3.toWei(0.1, "ether")})

then you should get something similar to

INFO [05-14|22:27:32] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x026b2abc55b84f0f748a8021e4ad7ef53ad9c7407d4af4a1877cf4dd313a4bea recipient=0x9f9A7216970EdBcDCe987fCa0a1b11831A7230d8
"0x026b2abc55b84f0f748a8021e4ad7ef53ad9c7407d4af4a1877cf4dd313a4bea"

> INFO [05-14|22:27:32] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=1 uncles=0 elapsed=407.08µs
>   INFO [05-14|22:27:32] Successfully sealed new block            number=1 hash=837722…84f695
>   INFO [05-14|22:27:32]  mined potential block                  number=1 hash=837722…84f695
>   INFO [05-14|22:27:32] Commit new mining work                   number=2 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=490.02µs

the transaction is then successful and you can check the balance by using

eth.getBalance(acct1) or (acct2)

hope this helps